# Send java encrypted mail with PGP based on recipient public key

Tags: java, encryption, jakarta-mail, bouncycastle, pgp

I wonder if the next case is real. Let's say that I need to send a mail in my java application. I also have a recipient's public key. All I want to do is to encrypt email message with the user's public key and send it to him. I'm using BouncyCastle for this purpose. I've managed only with encryption of email body text with user's PGP public key. Algorithm is follow:

1. User provides his pgp public key as text
2. I create `MimeMessage message;`
3. With the help of BouncyCastle I parse `PGPPublicKey`
4. With `PGPPublicKey` I encrypt the body `plain` text to `encrypted` text
5. Make `message.setText(encrypted)`

But the problem is that this mail is not perceived as PGP encrypted mail (I've tested with Thunderbird) and user is not able to decrypt the email 'encrypted' text. Seems like I have not enough knowledge to make this task work. Can someone help me?

Updates.

I do something like this while encrypting email content (I use Spring mail client)

```
MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, false, "utf-8");
helper.setTo("recepient's email here");
helper.setSubject("hello");
message.setContent(MyPGPUtil.encryptMessageWithPGPKey("very important message to encrypt", "recipient's public key as string"), "text/plain");
mailSender.send(message);
```

On the recipient side I got the message like on the picture below
[image: thunderbird]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your code / the resulting mimemessage data?

Comment: Are you trying to send an S/MIME message?  Or just a message where the fact that it's encrypted is part of the text of the message?  How is the user trying to decrypt the encrypted message?

Comment: I send only an encrypted part of the message (text). I was trying to create a S/MIME, but not succeed to encrypt message because every example was based on certificate and csm key storage, and I want to use only pgp public key.

Comment: For S/MIME I tried to use this code [bouncy castle example](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/mail/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/mail/smime/examples/SendSignedAndEncryptedMail.java) but I don't fully understand what is going on and how I can apply user's pgp public key. I suppose that I should modify lines 148-149 somehow to change the recepient "certificate", but don't know how to do it. @BillShannon

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a Bouncy Castle expert.  You might try asking on their mailing list, described at the [bottom of their Java page](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html).